# Cloud Formation Output Vars - Returning validation error for user access key id

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

Thanks in advance!

I'm creating a cloudformation template and would like to output the user access key and secret but to no avail...

It currently is not valid and gives me this error  Template contains errors.: Invalid template resource property 'XXXXXXuseraccesskey'.

Here's my template snippet;

```
"XXXXXXuseraccesskey": {
            "Type": "AWS::IAM::AccessKey",
            "Properties": {
                "UserName": {
                    "Ref": "XXXXXXuser"
                }
            }
        },

"YYYYYYuseraccesskey": {
            "Type": "AWS::IAM::AccessKey",
            "Properties": {
                "UserName": {
                    "Ref": "YYYYYYuser"
                }
            }
        },

    "outputs" : {
                "accesskeyforuser": {
                    "Ref": "XXXXXXuseraccesskey"
                },
                "secretkeyforuser": {
                    "Fn::GetAtt": ["XXXXXXuseraccesskey", "SecretAccessKey"]
                },
                "accesskeyforotheruser": {
                    "Ref": "YYYYYYuseraccesskey"
                },
                "secretkeyforotheruser": {
                    "Fn::GetAtt": ["YYYYYYuseraccesskey", "SecretAccessKey"]
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your output structure needs a "Value" section to reflect those mapped entries.

Here is a YAML sample of how to output an access key:

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Resources:
  user:
    Type: AWS::IAM::User
  XXXXXXuseraccesskey:
    Type: AWS::IAM::AccessKey
    Properties:
      UserName:
        Ref: user

Outputs:
  accesskeyforuser:
    Value:
      Ref: XXXXXXuseraccesskey
  secretkeyforuser:
    Value:
      Fn::GetAtt: ["XXXXXXuseraccesskey", "SecretAccessKey"]
```

Comment: Hey Jens, thanks for getting back to me, I tried using the Value property before but returned the same error but with 'Value' named instead of 'XXXXXXuseraccesskey'

Comment: It is not Value instead of XXXXXX, it is first level XXXXXX and on the second level, you have to define the Value.

Comment: I get this error returned when trying - Template contains errors.: Invalid template resource property 'accesskeyforuser'

Comment: I've just realised I was putting the output inside the resource tag....